# Создание графика в виде точек с разными изображениями на одной вертикальной оси

Tags: c#, c++, график

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла такая ситуация, что мне надо составить график, в котором часть точек (ниже определённой кривой) обозначается точкой, а другая часть (выше её) - крестиком, причём все точки находятся на одной вертикальной прямой.

Графическими редакторами не владею, так что мне проще воспользоваться написанием программы на C++ или на C# Windows Forms, благо массив данных имеется.

Есть ли какая-то возможность воспользоваться стандартным компонентом ChartBox или надо искать другое решение?

Comment: Да, конечно есть.

Comment: Это разово или клиент с GUI нужен? А то Excel с простой условной функцией вполне справится с поставленной задачей, как мне кажется

Comment: Разово, однако, как бы это странно ни звучало, я не настолько хорошо владею Excel'ем, чтобы понять, как это можно сделать. Обычный график не подходит.